# Generalizing limits of sums, products, and quotients of sequences to abstract topological spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

Introductory real analysis books usually prove a [list of properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) about limits of sequences of real and complex numbers. Suppose $\lim x_n=x$ and $\lim y_n=y$. Then:

1. $\lim (x_n+y_n) = x+y$
2. $\lim c x_n = cx$ (where $c \in F$ for some field $F$)
3. $\lim x_n y_n = xy$
4. $\lim x_n^p=x^p$
5. $\lim \frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{x}$ (provided for all $n$, $x_n \ne 0$ and $x \ne 0$)
6. $\lim \frac{x_n}{y_n}=\frac{x}{y}$ (provided for all $n$, $x_n \ne 0$, $y_n \ne 0$, $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$)

However, these results can be generalized **beyond** sequences of real & complex numbers to more abstract sequences in more general metric and topological spaces. I would like to prove these results for an **arbitrary** metric space. However, the problem is, as far as I know, these operations (addition, multiplication and division) are only defined for *numbers*. So in an *abstract* metric or topological space, does $x_n+y_n$ have meaning?

How would one generalize these properties to abstract metric and topological spaces? Should you start with topological field extensions, topological algebras over a topological field, normed algebras, or something else? And just how general can you make these results? What is the *most* general topological space in which the operations $x_n+y_n$, $x_n \times y_n$, $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$, etc. make sense and all 6 properties of limits hold? Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Please stop trying to bump this question by making trivial edits. It's really annoying.

Comment: Please stop bumping this question by making trivial edits. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The group of real numbers $(\Bbb R,+,0,-)$ with its usual topology is a *topological group*: The addition $+:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ (where $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ has the product topology) and the negation $-:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ are continuous maps. These properties of $\Bbb R$ are exactly what leads to formulas like 
$$\lim(x_n+y_n) = x+y\quad \text{ and } \quad \lim(-x_n)=-x$$
the reason being that the sequence $(x_n,y_n)_n\subseteq\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ converges to $(x,y)$, thus, as a continuous map preserves limits, the image sequence $(+(x_n,y_n))_n = (x_n+y_n)_n$ converges to the sum $+(x,y) = x+y$. By the same reasoning, we have $(-(x_n))_n\to -x$.

Replacing addition $+$ with multiplication $\cdot:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, though, we don't get a group but rather a monoid $(\Bbb R,\cdot,1)$, and it is topological in the sense that $\cdot$ is continuous. By the same reasoning as above, we have $\lim(x_ny_n)=xy$.
We regain a topological group, however, if we restrict to non-zero real numbers $\Bbb R_\times$, since the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ is continuous. So it follows that $\lim(1/x_n)=1/x$.

Examples are topological groups are

- The circle $S^1$ with the multiplication and topology inherited from the complex numbers.
- The group $\text{Aut}(X)$ of homeomorphisms on a compact Hausdorff space $X$. The multiplication is the composition of two maps, and the topology is the [*compact-open topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact-open_topology)
- Any normed vector space $(V,||-||)$ has a topology induced by the norm, and this topology makes the addition $+$ and the negation $-$, as well as scalar multiplication $\Bbb R\times V\to V$ continuous. That's why we speak of *topological vector space*.

---

I'm going to address your desire for a structure where all these properties hold: We assume that our structure $X$ has an addition, an inner multiplication, and an outer scalar multiplication with a field $F$, subject to the following rules

1. $(x+y)+z = x+(y+z)$
2. $x+y = y+x$
3. There is an element $0$ such that $0+x = x+0 = x$
4. For each $x\in X$, there is a $-x\in X$ such that $x+(-x) = 0$.
5. $(λ\mu)x = λ(\mu x)$
6. $\lambda(x+y) = λx + λy$
7. $(λ+\mu)x = λx + \mu x$
8. $(xy)z = x(yz)$
9. $xy = yx$
10. There is an element $1_X\in X$ such that $1_X x = x1_X = x$
11. For each $x\in X\setminus\{0\}$, there is an $x^{-1}=\frac1x$ such that $x/x=1_X$
12. $(x+y)z = xz+yz$
13. $(λx)y = λ(xy)$

where $x,y,z\in X$ and $λ,\mu\in F$, and $x/y$ is another notation for $xy^{-1}=y^{-1}x$

One could subsume these rules by saying that $(X,+,0,-,\cdot,1_X,^{-1})$ is a field satisfying the rules 5, 6, 7, and 13. Note that we can deduce some more properties from these

- $0_F x = λ0_X = 0_X$
- $-(λx) = (-λ)x = λ(-x)$
- $1_F x = x$. For if $1_Fx=y$, then 
  $$ 1_F x = (1_F1_F)x = 1_F(1_F x) = 1_F y $$
  thus $1_F(x-y) = 0$. Now if $x\ne y$, then $z=(x-y)$ has an inverse,
  hence $$1_F1_X = 1_F(zz^{-1}) = (1_Fz)z^{-1} = 0_Xz^{-1} = 0_X$$
  which again implies that 
  $$λw = (λ1_F)(1_Xw) = (λ(1_F1_X))w = λ0_Xw = 0_Xw = 0$$
  for any $λ\in F$ and $w\in X$, which is probably not what you want.
- The map $i:λ\mapsto λ1_X$ is a field homomorphism. For if $λ,\mu\in F$, 
  then $(λ+\mu)1_X = λ1_X + \mu1_X$ and 
  $(λ\mu)1_X = λ(1_X(\mu1_X)) = (λ1_X)(\mu1_X)$. So either $i\equiv0$,
  or $i$ is an embedding of $F$ into $X$. But if $i\equiv0$, then
  $λx=λ(1_Xx)=(λ1_X)x=0_Fx = 0$ for any $λ\in F$ and $x\in X$.

The last item is why we can regard $F$ as a subfield of $X$, so whacka's remark about $X/F$ being a field extension is justified.

Now $X$ is equipped with a topology, otherwise we could not talk about limits of sequences. Note that if we equip $X\times X$ with the product topology, then sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ converge to $x$ and $y$, respectively, if and only if $(x_n,y_n)_n$ converges to $(x,y)$ in $X\times X$. So the property $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n+y_n)_n = x+y$ simply means that addition $+:X\times X\to X$ preserves limits of convergent sequences, thus is sequentially continuous (as opposed to being continuous, which is slightly stronger). So the limit properties you stated hold if and only if addition, multiplication, and inversion are sequentially continuous. One could call such a structure a *sequentially topological field* or something like that.

Comment: But these results aren't specific to $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, they hold in $\mathbb{C}$ and more abstract metric spaces. That's the point of my question - what's the most abstract / general we can make this result?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: I would say, the most general objects where these results hold are objects that are equipped with a topology (because of $\lim$) as well as a binary relation such that these two structures are compatible with each other, and that's just a topological monoid (top. group, top. vector space).

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your mention of vector spaces. However, take the property that $\lim x_n y_n = xy$. This property doesn't hold in a vector space, because multiplication of vectors is undefined. So I am thinking the most abstract we can have these properties is for a ring or field. But I am not sure if there might be more abstract spaces where these results still hold.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: Oh, I see, you want all these formulas to be defined and to hold at once, in a single structure. Well, then you would have topological field, i.e. a field $(F,+,0,-,*,1,^{-1})$ such that $(F,+,0,-)$ and $(F\setminus\{0\},*,1,^{-1})$ are topological groups.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: Actually, since you don't require $*$ to be commutative, a skew field would suffice. And since you want to multiply $x_n$ by a scalar $c\in\Bbb R$, this skew field would at the same time have to be a topological vector space. That means it is a [topological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_algebra), but one in which you can divide elements.

Comment: We also require that the operations are continuous (in the appropriate sense). Simply having a topological structure on an algebra is not sufficient. We probably also want the topology to be metrisable (since we are talking about sequences), so we probably want a Frechet algebra (or non-complete variants thereof).

Comment: @SamM: I know, I thought it was clear by now that every operation was assumed continuous, so I didn't explicitely mention it any more. But we don't need a metrisable topology, you can talk about sequences in any topology. On the other hand, if your space is first-countable, the rules in the OP's question are equivalent to continuity of addition, multiplication, etc.

Comment: Hi Stefan, can you edit your answer to generalize it beyond the real/complex numbers? What you said about skew fields / topological algebras is interesting - can elaborate on this in your answer?

Comment: Also, vector spaces don't usually allow division of its elements (nor do topological algebras). What structure do you end up with when you confer division to a topological vector space?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: You end up with a division algebra.

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: I just read that there are only three associative division algebras over the reals. Do you want your structure to be associative (the multiplication I mean)? And do you want $F$ to be the field of real numbers?

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your reply. I'm looking for the most general kind of structure in which all of these properties hold. So not associative if we don't need it for these limit rules to hold. And where $F$ can be any arbitrary field, not necessarily $\mathbb{R}$. (Actually, maybe an algebra over a ring $R$ would be more general -- as we don't need scalar multiplicative inverses for these limit rules to hold, right?)

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: But you want to add, multiply, and divide. So you have to say how these operations are related. Do you want distributivity ($a(b+c)=ab+ac$)?. And how is division related to mulitplication? I assume you want $1/b*b=1$, so $1/b$ is just a notation for $b^{-1}$? But if you don't have commutativity, you need to specify whether $a/b$ means $ab^{-1}$ or $b^{-1}a$?

Comment: @Stefan-Hamcke I see your point! I don't know what answer to give, though, e.g. between $ab^{−1}$ or $b^{−1}a$ (to be honest, I have never seen a multiplicative inverse, e.g. $b^{−1}$, defined for vectors, nor have I even seen vector multiplication defined outside of the "dot product"). But to answer your question, I suppose it would be most straightforward for our purposes simply to impose associativity, commutativity, and distributivity of multiplication, yes? (Even though we acknowledge they wouldn't technically be necessary for these the limit properties to hold, correct?)

Comment: @EthanAlvaree: One more question: Do you want the addition $+$ to have negative elements, that is, for each $x\in X$ there is $-x$ such that $x+(-x)=0$ ?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Sure, I guess that extra assumption won't hurt.

Comment: @StefanHamcke: There are only three _finite-dimensional_ associative division algebras over the reals.  There are many more that are infinite-dimensional (for instance, $\mathbb{R}(x)$).

Answer (score 4):

Indeed the algebra of limits holds (for sums and scalar multiples) in any normed space. The proof is identical. The remaining algebra of limits hold in any normed algebra. Note here that the norm on an algebra imust satisfy $\lVert xy\rVert\leq\lVert x\rVert\lVert y\rVert$ for all $x,y$ in the algebra. Also note that *non-zero* must be replaced by *invertible* in the multiplication of the algebra.

A particular example of such an algebra is the space of all continuous, complex-valued functions on a compact Hausdorff space, equipped with the supremum norm and point-wise operations.

(n.b. I typed this on my phone, so it is undoubtedly filled with the wrong words and bad typos)

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. What do you mean by a normed "algebra"? I have studied abstract algebraic structures such the ring, field, vector space, etc. But is an "algebra" in the same category as these? And if so, how would you define it?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field

Comment: @SamM, do these properties hold in *any* normed algebra, or do we also require it to be "topologically complete" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) or "completely metrizable" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_metrizable_space)?

Comment: It isn't a property of completeness. What's really going on here is that the operations $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ are continuous with respect to the topology on the space (see the comments in the above). In other words, whenever we have a set $X$, which has some kind of algebraic structure *and* a topological structure  for which the algebraic operations are (jointly) continuous. Then the identities you want.

Answer (score 3):

To talk about things like addition, multiplication, multiplicative identity, unlimited division, scalars from $F$ and for the notation $\frac{a}{b}$ to make sense, you're already talking about a field extension of $F$.

Then (almost by definition) a structure satisfies your list of properties $\iff$ it's a topological field which is also a field extension of $F$. There is some redundancy in the list:

- $(3)\implies(2)$
- $(3)\implies (4)_{p\ge0}$
- $(3)\land(5)\implies(4)_{p\in\Bbb Z}$
- $(4)_{p\in\Bbb Z}\implies(5)$
- $(3)\land(5)\implies(6)$

Just throw away $(4)$ from the outset. We can get some other structures by discarding other conditions:

- If one throws out $(2)$, then we have a topological field with no relation to $F$. If it is locally compact and not discrete, this is called a local field, and the topology is induced from a metric which is itself induced from an absolute value function.
- If one throws out $(6)$ then multiplication isn't necessarily commutative so it is a topological division algebra, aka skew field, that contains the field $F$.
- If one throws out $(2)\land(6)$, it's a topological skew field with no relation to $F$.
- If one throws out $(5)\land(6)$ then it is a topological ring that contains $F$.
- If one throws out $(2)\land(5)\land(6)$ then it is a topological ring.
- If one throws out $(2)\land(3)\land(5)\land(6)$ then it's a topological abelian (additive) group.
- If one throws out $(1)\land(2)\land(5)\land(6)$ then it's a topological (multiplicative) group.
- If one throws out $(3)\land(5)\land(6)$ then it's a topological vector space over $F$.

Essentially, *first* figure out the algebraic structure you want, *then* add the word topological in front of it. One can still get things that don't have names, I suppose. (For instance, consider a topological ring in which inversion is continuous on the subspace of two-sided *units*, or take one of the above listed objects and append topological conditions on.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You said a structure (almost by definition) satisfies these properties if and only if it is a topological *field* extension of $F$. However, the other answers & comments talk about a topological algebra (vector space with multiplication) **over** a field $F$. I am not sure which structure to use for these limit rules, but I'm currently leaning toward topological algebra. Is one space more general than the other?

Comment: Thinking about it a little bit more, I realize that either way, I would need the notion of a topological field. Because even topological algebras are defined over *topological* fields. The confusing thing is, the topological field would satisfy the limit properties AND the topological algebra over that topological field would also satisfy the same limit properties, simultaneously. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @EthanAlvaree Your condition (5) says every nonzero element has an inverse, and condition (6) implicitly assumes multiplication is commutative, so together they imply the structure is itself a field. Any field that contains $F$ is called a field extension of $F$. Most often one uses the term "algebra" to refer to a ring that contains a given field. Also, sure, I see nothing confusing about both a field and a vector space over it being topological.

Comment: I am just learning that an *algebra* (over a field) is a vector space endowed with multiplication $\cdot: V \times V \to V$, although I have never seen multiplication of vectors defined except for the *dot product*, which doesn't satisfy our property #3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field